# error opening websites using webbrowser module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

while using webbrowser module to open websites, got this error

code:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('youtube.com')
```

error:

```
gio: file:///home/swastik/Python/Programs/F.R.I.D.A.Y./youtube.com: Error when getting information for file “/home/swastik/Python/Programs/F.R.I.D.A.Y./youtube.com”: No such file or directory
```

Comment: works just fine for me.

Comment: webbrowser.open("https://") try this and show us the result in comments.

Comment: @edusanketdk probably a browser specific issue, depending on how different browsers handle protocol-less urls.

Comment: @edusanketdk now it works fine. thanks....

Answer (score 1):

You should write full url like

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com")
```

then it would work fine
if you don't want to open this with your default browser you can use

```
webbrowser.get('chrome %s').open_new_tab('https://www.youtube.com')
```